# Bluemix dashboard: Unable to update route (BXNUI0030E)

Tags: ibm-cloud

This error seems like a Bluemix internal error to me.

I try to add another route using the new Bluemix dashboard to one of my liberty apps and the error message I get is:

> BXNUI0030E: The 'xxxxxx.au-syd.mybluemix.net' route wasn't mapped to
>   the 'xxxxx-arya' app because a problem occurred contacting Cloud
>   Foundry.  Try again later. If you see this message again, go to the
>   Bluemix status page to check whether a service or component has an
>   issue. If the problem continues, click the Account and Support icon in
>   the top menu bar, click Get help, and search for help or get support.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please open a ticket so that the support team can look at your specific environment. See: https://ibm.biz/support_widget_instructions

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not clear to identify cause of the problem. The message just tells Cloud Foundry command behind Web interface failed to create map-route, but it didn't tell what exactly happen. Please run below commands to know what happened during creating map-route and fix the problem;

1. Login into the space by cfcli;

   cf login -a api.au-syd.bluemix.net -u  -p  -o  -s
2. List all routes in the space and make sure the app or the map-route are there;

   cf routes
3. Create map-route by command;

   cf map-route APPNAME au-syd.mybluemix.net --hostname NEW-HOSTNAME
4. Check error message and fix the problem

   *) Most common problem is duplicate map-route name if the hostname used in in other spaces. Please contact Bluemix Support with your new hostname if you cannot find the hostname in your organizations.